# I want to 'disable' the physical power button

Tags: android, android-hardware

Hi i am new to android application development, i want disable power button action(screen on and off) into my application.
Please provide solution for this.

Comment: You can't with stock OS

Comment: And why would you want to do that? :?

Answer (score 0):

how about override it

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
                    Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                    sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
                    return true;
            }

            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: I want restrict screen off when click on power button

Comment: then you have to create it inside a sticky service

Comment: Can you provide sample snippet code 
Thanks in advance